# How do I get Advanced Custom Fields data, from another WordPress of mine?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a website, where I put some services from that company. Now I am creating a new one for them and I need to show again those services.

I did it using Advanced Custom Fields and custom templates, so my question is:

Can I now connect to the database of the first webpage, retrieve the custom fields data and show it to the second one?

The thing is that it has to be updated at the same time, so I need to use the same database for both.

I've seen that I can connect to an external database:

```
$mydb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'database', 'localhost' );
$rows = $mydb->get_results( "select Name from my_table" );
```

But I looked up on the first database and I'm not finding, where is supposed to be saved that information. Where is that information saved?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

To connect to a remote Database the remote server should be open to external connections, almost any host do not allow this.

The best thing to do is use [WP REST API](https://v2.wp-api.org/) to create a `service` that you can consume from an external site.

Comment: I guess an API would be great and the right thing to do, but i have no time for that, i have to find a fastest solution. Thanks

Comment: I know old school way, create ajax action function for in source site, then do get_file from second site with php 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_services', 'get_services_init' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_services', 'get_services_init' );
function get_services_init() {
 //get whats needed, push to array, encode to JSON, echo and die();
}
to get json in second site file_get_contents('https://services-source-site/admin-ajax.php?action=get_services');

Answer (score 1):

The data from ACF is saved into the meta tables of the according post type, for example wp_postmeta. There, look for meta_key with the name of your fields. There should alway be two: One starting with an underscore, which is the reference to the field definition, and one without an undersscore, containing the actual data for the according post ID.

As you didn't explain in detail on what amount of information you need and how you want to display the data, you'll need to take it from there. But:
If it's not just field information that you need to retrieve and display, things will get complex (and potentially dangerous) quickly. Make sure you create a read-only account to connect to the other DB. Also, if the original DB is on another host, you might run into several issues regarding firewalls and SQL configuation (localhost only config etc.).
While basically anything is technically possible, e.g. "linking" to the other DB by using views, database synchronization, ..., I strongly recommend to keep it simple and consider a simple scheduled export + import of the required information into a seperate DB and get it from there.

Comment: It would be just retrieving acf data, so that can work. I’ll have to allow CORS and try this out. I was expecting a acf sharing data plugin or sonething like that, but well i’ll have to try and find out an answer.